# React handle error if user enters incorrect query format into search bar

Tags: reactjs, api, date

I built a React app that fetches data from the New York Times Bestseller Books API and allows users to search for different lists by the publish date.

The NYTimes built this API so that dates [must be entered in YYYY-MM-DD format](https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/books-product/1/routes/lists/%7Bdate%7D/%7Blist%7D.json/get) for search queries. I added a placeholder in the search bar to inform the user of the correct format, but I want to know how I can handle the error if the user enters the date in the incorrect format (such as MM-DD-YYYY). Currently the app just crashes.

I should mention this is just a personal / student project for my portfolio.

Here is the **updated** code for my search bar:

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
     date: "",
  });


  const getBestsellersByDate = async (date) => {
    const response = await fetch(url + "/bestsellers/" + date, {
      method: "get",
      headers: {},
    });
    const fetchedBestsellers = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: "getBestsellers", payload: fetchedBestsellers });
  };
```

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      if (Date.parse(formData.date)) {
        // books index from search date
        getBestsellersByDate(formData.date);
        // date specs for list corresponding to search
        getBestsellersArchiveDate(formData.date);
        setFormData({
          date: "",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      event.preventDefault();
       alert.error(
         <div
           style={{ background: "#cf6679", color: "#000000", padding: "5px" }}
         >
           Please log in!
         </div>
       );
      console.log("enter valid date!");
    }
  };
```

```
  <div className="search-form_container">
          <Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="date"
              pattern="/^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/"
              className="search-form mr-sm-2"
              value={formData.date}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
            />
            <button id="btn-search" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </Form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens when the api call fails? I would also recommend using react-query with graceful error handeling as well. https://react-query.tanstack.com/

Comment: The backend server I built (which makes the actual API call to NYTimes) sends back a HTTP status of 500. React throws a "cannot map over undefined" error, since it didn't get any data from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your `handleSubmit` function:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(Date.parse(formData.date)){
       getBestsellersByDate(formData.date);
       setFormData({
         date: "",
       });
    } else {
       console.log("enter valid date!!!");
    }
  };
```

it will try to parse a `Date` from a string that user has entered and if it is a valid date, it will call API, otherwise, it will console.log the error. Obviously, you can show the error using other components like `snackbar`.

Comment: How does Date.parse know the correct date format (i.e. a "valid date")?

Comment: the default format is similar to what you want (`yyyy-mm-dd`).

Comment: Also -- not sure how to prevent the page from erroring out so I can display a snackbar type of component.

Comment: you can use the above code, or use `try-catch` to prevent your app from crashing. in the above case you can use `Snackbar` in the `else` statement (in `try-catch` method in your `catch` phrase). now, you can show error using simple validation in textfield or using snackbar. if you are not familiar with them see https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/ and https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/ respectively

Comment: I can't seem to get the try catch block to work. I edited my original code to show the handleSubmit function in it's current state - what's wrong with the way I executed this?

Comment: you should use ` catch (error) {` that `error` value shows the error you have encountered!

Comment: Ok! Yeah this just doesn't work for me even with that adjustment. Thanks anyways. If you want to clone the repo and check it out, this code is in `src/pages/home.jsx` at line 129. 
github.com/mickey-vershbow/books-frontend3.git

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern property.

At yow Form.Control add a property call pattern.

Write down the format you want

pattern=“\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}”

I recommend you to search for the correct regex

Comment: I added the pattern property to Form.Control, how would I then implement this into the logic for the handleSubmit?

Comment: you dont have to do anything click on the submit button, youll see it

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting the expected result. The app still crashes rather than showing the user an alert about the date format. Here is the github repo if you want to clone it (just npm install and then npm start) and try it out. https://github.com/mickey-vershbow/books-frontend3.git

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern to validate your input and string.prototype.match function will return your input value is compatible with your regex pattern or not.
Here is a working example for you

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const onChange = (event) => {
    const dateFormatPattern = /^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    const { value } = event.target;
    if(value.match(dateFormatPattern)) {
      setError("")
    }else {
      setError("something went wrong")
    }
  };

  return <Fragment>
    <input onChange={onChange} />
    {error}
  </Fragment>;
}
```

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dateFormatPattern = /^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    const { value } = event.target;
    if(value.match(dateFormatPattern)) {
        // books index from search date
        getBestsellersByDate(formData.date);
        // date specs for list corresponding to search
        getBestsellersArchiveDate(formData.date);
        setFormData({
          date: "",
        });
      }
      setError("")
    }else {
      props.history.push("/home");
      console.log("enter valid date!");
    }
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate this approach with my existing code -- can you explain how this would work with what I've already built? Do I need to write that "onChange" code you provided in my handleSubmit function?

Comment: I added your function above. Firstly, I defined a regex pattern with compatible your date format and then I read the input value to control this input value is a right format or not. String.prototype.match will return the input value if you are giving the desired format otherwise it will return null.

Comment: Thanks for this, very cool. It produces an error saying "cannot read property 'match' of undefined", any idea what the problem could be? I tried writing  `if(formData.date.match(dateFormatPattern)`, but then when I entered the date correctly, it produced the "enter valid date!" console error.